# What does the Encryped icon mean

Tags: mount, icons, encryption

I just upgrade my Ubuntu from 20 to 22 today. After rebooting, I found there is a new icon in my Favrites bar.

[image]

And when I click on it with the right button, a `Mount` poped up:

[image]

And on the top of the screen, a circle is spinning:

[image]

What is this? Is it there because I installed a duplicated OS (win) with the Ubuntu OS on my PC? I just tried to enter the password of `sudo` and the password of my login account of the Win, but when I clicked the `Unlock`, nothing happened. The icon is always there...

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu Core 22?  as it's a *headless* (server) system, only 20.04/22.04 have the desktop option (not 20 or 22)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed shows an encrypted volume that either is on a removable drive, or that is announced in your `/etc/fstab` file. If the latter, then either remove the line that announces volume from your `/etc/fstab` file, or add the option `x-gvfs-hide` to that line to not have it displayed. If the former, then the system must be seeing that volume as a removable drive. If physically, you cannot remove it, then you could announce it in `/etc/fstab` without mounting it to hide it.

An easy option, but that hides all volumes from the dock, is to turn "Show volumes and devices" off in Settings - Appearance, "Configure dock behavior" (under the section "Dock").